# How to detect an image in a news paper and play a video relevant to it using augmented reality?

Tags: augmented-reality

I have planned to detect an image in a news paper play the video relevant to it. I have seen several news paper reading AR apps include this feature. But i couldn't find how to do so. How can I do it??
I dont expect any code. But like to know what are the steps I should follow to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to browse through the available marker-based AR SDKs - such SDKs let you defined in advance the database of images you would like to detect and respond to, and once any of these images is detected during runtime, you get some kind of an event with data on the detected image.

Vuforia is considered a good one and it has good samples, so it is supposed to be easier to start with. You should also check out Kudan, and there are more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer